# Report Builder 3.0 WHERE clause with CASE statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a drill through report that works well with the main report.  I would like to modify the drill through report but am having trouble with the WHERE clause.  The main report is a summary with different aging buckets and looks like this:

```
Team         Total       30         60        90        120

 A            xxxx      xxxx      xxxxx      xxxxx      xxxxx
 B            xxxx      xxxx       xxxx      xxxxx      xxxxx
 C            xxxx      xxxx       xxxx      xxxxx      xxxxx
```

The current report only contains hyperlinks on the Team values.  When a user clicks on one of the Teams, the drill through report displays the details for the records that make up the total amount.  Works great.

What I would like to do is to modify the drill through report so the user can select one of the amount fields (30 / 60 /90 /120) for a particular team.

The current WHERE clause on the drill through report looks like this: "WHERE  a.lgp = Parm1".  Parm1 is the field value for the Team the user selects.

I would like modify the WHERE clause so that it will work if the user selects the team or 1 of the amount fields.  Can I use a CASE statement for this in the WHERE clause?

If the user selects an amount field the WHERE clause would look something like this for 30 / 60 / 90: 
WHERE a.lgp = Parm1 and ar.aging_bucket = Parm2.

Parm2 would be either 1,2, 3.  However, if they select 120, then the WHERE clause would be something like this:

a.lgp = Parm1 and ar.aging_bucket =>4.

I could create 3 copies of the drill through report (1) Total, (2) 30 / 60 / 90, and (3) 120 but then I have to maintain 3 reports.  I would rather modify the WHERE clause to handle all 3 of these situations.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, or else someone probably would have chimed in by now and told us how. Plus I've tried similar things in the past.. but...

The following displays all of the information in the table.

```
declare @foo int = 1
select * from MySuperCoolTable
where @foo = 1
```

So you might be able to do:

```
select column1, column2 from TheNameOfTheTable
where
(((@param1 = 30) or (@param1 = 60) or (param1 = 90)) and ar.aging_bucket =>4 and whatever else here)
or
(@param1 = 120 and whatever else here)
```

Obviously this was just thrown together but hopefully this puts you on the right track to something that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll use this as a starting point and see what I can do.  Thanks again.